# Django - View Other user profile

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.6 to create a web app.. I have users and user profiles and have designed templates to display the profile information of the user.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'xyz'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ... other fields ...
```

I have various edit buttons on the template where the user views his profile information. Also, a user can view another user's profile. In this case, the user should not be able to see the edit, delete or add buttons.

Are there in-built security mechanisms for this? What is the best way to implement this using Django 1.6?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a default set of [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) (change, add, delete) for each model. You can use them in your template to hide the buttons or use a simple check if the user shown is also the user viewing the page.

```
{% if perms.accounts.change_user %}
Edit
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if edit_user == user %}
Edit
{% endif %}
```

Then also in your view on a POST request you want to check if someone is trying to change another user and return a HttpResponseForbidden.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

...

if not request.user == user:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... Was curious to know if there are alternative simple solutions, to avoid ifs in templates.. :)

Comment: Off the top of my head... you could 1) use a variable is_own_profile which is either empty or holds the name of a css class which makes all buttons in all child elements hidden, or 2) execute a little javascript function to hide the buttons if is_own_profile is false, so you could get away with a single "if".

Comment: Doesn't this solution introduces security threats?

Comment: No, a user can always construct and send his own POST request if there is a form & button or not. That's why you need to verify on the backend if the user is allowed to make changes.